# Xamarin Forms Android startup issue with AppCompat Theme note

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, crash, android-appcompat

I've got the following on the app start:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ ... .SplashActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme 
(or descendant) with this activity.
```

However, this is my SplashScreen activity definition:

```
[Activity(NoHistory = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView }, DataScheme = "wоwоnder", Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[]{ Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable}, DataScheme = "http",DataPathPrefix = "/Wowonder/",DataHost = "demo.Wоwоnder.com")]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

Also, my theme in styles is as follows:

```
  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

as well as AppTheme:

So, I fully got stuck with it!

Comment: Hi, your codes works well for me. Have you tried to  delete bin/obj folder and restart Visual Studio? Or maybe you need do something on `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` or `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 `, like uninstall and install it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the responding, however, I did handle that. But just now quite sure what actually helped, as I was doing lots of different manipulations, including the mentioned folders deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was really quite strange and I am not fully sure what of the things exactly did help, but what I done was:

- removing obj/bin folders;
- "Clean Solution" option;
- restarting Visual Studio.

Any manipulations with Activities (views) classes and `style` files wasn't quite effective. I mean, the exception did stop to appear after such type of manipulations, but after complete reverting of the files changed (the style files), the exception disappeared anyways (probably, because of some cleaning mentioned above).

I also did re-installed some older/newer versions of XF in the meantime, but again, after reverting all the files (source files) changed to what I had in the beginning, the problem gone, which means, that was some issue with bin/obj folders content.

Answer (score 0):

it Good you could fix it ;)

1. Remove obj/bin folders;
2. "Build Solution";
3. Unload/Reload Project